# php domdocument xml troubles when <>& in items

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse this XML:

```
<data>
<item field="abcdef '<>&" row="another text" />
</data>
```

I should get **abcdef '<>&** for getAttribute('field') and **another text** for  getAttribute('row'). But if my data contains <>& etc XML is not parsed correctly. How can I parse it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's malformed XML. You need to encode `'<>&` as `&apos;&lt;&gt;&amp;`. This is what well formed XML looks like:

```
<data>
<item field="abcdef &apos;&lt;&gt;&amp;" row="another text" />
</data>
```

You need to tidy the XML before you can parse it with an XML parser.

Comment: thanks, and any idea how to do it if I obtained this "untidy" XML? I would like to clean it before parsing. Unfortunately I don't know how...

Comment: Is the code that generates the malformed XML under your control? Ideally, you generate well formed XML and don't need to tidy anything.

Comment: that would be nice but unfortunately I cannot control that code which generates this XML.

Comment: You could try your luck with [PHP tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) which is really for HTML but it might work for you. Other than that, you could do some manual string manipulation. But be careful to only impact special characters in attribute values and text nodes.